# How can i right align a Text Field in the settings bundle of an app , iOS?

Tags: ios, alignment, bundle, settings.bundle

I have in my settings bundle of my application two text fields , where the user can give latitude and longitude values.

The bundle settings look like this :

[image]

As you see the values (43.46 and -3.81) are left aligned.

Is there a way to right align them so it looks better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only answer to this question is to add spaces on the title of the text field , till your values move to the left side.

Is not very delicate , but looks better than this.

Comment: @davidf2281 Karim's answer doesn't work now, if it ever did. You simply get a static 'Title' with his method and the user asked for an editable 'Text Field'.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in in-app settings view. I have not tried it with settings.

Open property list file as a source and paste the following to the for each entry you want right-aligned:

```
        <key>IASKTextAlignment</key>
        <string>IASKUITextAlignmentCenter</string>
```

Or do the same through the plist editor.

Comment: This is actually only relevant if you are using the InAppSettingsKit library for an in-app settings view.

Comment: Yes, you are quite right - I've only been using in-app settings view. I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in different way. You have to add a Title preference item. and add titles and values inside that. 
I have a screenshot here,

[image: Settings bundle plist file]

And the resulting settings screen will look like this,

[image]

Comment: If this worked at one time, it no longer works. The value you are specifying is simply a normal title done in a more complicated than necessary way. The question asked for an editable 'Text Field' not a static 'Title'.